# Want to check the curly brace existence. But return false

Tags: java, regex

I tried to check the curly braces existence of a `String`. But it returns `false`. Can anyone give me a solution.

```
String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[{]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's wrong with `code.contains("{")`?

Answer (score 2):

Needs comments

```
// the first character must be a {
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[{]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
// the entire strings must match so you only accept "{" and nothing else.
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

I suspect you didn't want `^` and you wanted `find()` instead of `matches()`  Find will accept the first substring which matches.

Answer (score 1):

`^` means the start of the string. It should be removed, since you want to find it anywhere in the string.

Oh and don't use `matches`, use `find` instead. `matches` checks whether the whole string matches the pattern, `find` looks for the pattern in the string.

```
String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[{]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Though, `contains("{")`, as Rohit mentioned, would be simpler.

```
String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
System.out.println(code.contains("{"));
```

If you want to do a replacement, `Matcher` does have a `replaceAll` function, but so does `String`. This adds a new-line before every `{`: (`\\{` is an alternate way of escaping `{`)

```
String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
System.out.println(code.replaceAll("\\{", "\n{"));
```

Now if I'm correct in where you're going with this, you can't do code indentation with regex. It's incremental / recursive, which doesn't work (well) in regex. You'll need to iterate through the string manually to do this.

Comment: I want to find every curly braces and add a new line and tabs for it. Is it possible with matcher??

Comment: Yes Thanks! I'm going to convert this string to the convention. But it is impossible with replace all. Give me a way to do it please.

Comment: @JhonF It's not exactly easy, though there should be more than enough open-source implementations out there. [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/), for example, is an open-source Java IDE that has many options for code formatting.

Comment: @JhonF You can, and I certainly think it's a nice little exercise, but it's quite a bit of work, and there are so many implementations out there that it should rarely be much more than an exercise - it would be better to use a tried and tested implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't allow for other characters besides what is included.  Also, I fixed your regex - `^` matches at the beginning of the `String` only, so you'd have to have a `{` at the beginning of your `String`.

`Matcher.matches()` is going to try to make the entire string match the regex.  `Matcher.find()` is checking to see if the regex pattern exists anywhere within the `String`

```
  String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[{]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
  System.out.println(m.find());
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `code.contains("{")` as @Rohit Jain suggests, or use this as your regex:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^*.[{]*.");`

Without the wildcards, the pattern will only match exactly one string, namely `"{"`